# preventing windows from prompting to open when running a javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, scripting, batch-file

I have a javascript called `fancy.js`. I have a batch script that calls out to this `fancy.js` several times.

When i run this batch script on my computer, it runs fine.

When i run this batch script on a clean vm created for testing the script, it will prompt the user to open the file every time `fancy.js` is called. The dialog is similar to this: "do you want to open this file. File type: jscript script file, Publisher: unknown publisher".

**How do i prevent it from prompting the user every time it attempts to run the `fancy.js`?**

It was run inside an admin command prompt on a windows 7vm with a win7 host.

I have this `cscript //h:cscript` at the top of the batch file. This is to prevent some prompts from coming up in older versions of windows.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Added some more information regarding the output of the prompt. It is also claiming an unknown publisher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I was attempting to run the batch script and the `fancy.js` from a network drive.

Once i moved it to a local drive to the VM it ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unblocking it? Windows flags stuff as not secure when coming from a different source.

Right click on the file and get its properties. Click Unblock.

Comment: I was attempting to run the scripts from a network drive. Moving them to a local drive to the vm fixed the issue. Thanks for the assistance